# Incrementing a cell value in pandas dataframe based on multiple column conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to increment the integer value present in `column_3` based on checks in `column_1` and `column_2`.

```
  | column_1 | column_2 | column_3
0 |    a     |    x     |    1 
1 |    b     |    y     |    1 
2 |    c     |    z     |    1
```

I want to increment the value present in `column_3` by `1` if `column_1 = a` and `column_2 = x`.

I tried the following approach but it does not work -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "column_1": ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
    "column_2": ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    "column_3": [1,1,1]
})

df[(df['column_1']=='a') & (df['column_2']=='x')]['column_3'] += 1
```

Checking the `df` output after running the above code gives the same dataframe.

After Jupyter showed the warning I made use of the `.loc` but still it does not work.

```
df.loc[df.column_1.isin(['a']) & df.column_2.isin(['x'])]['column_3'].iat[0] += 1
```

How exactly do we achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is correct way, but is necessary also remove `][` and `iat`:

```
df.loc[(df['column_1']=='a') & (df['column_2']=='x'), 'column_3'] += 1

print (df)
  column_1 column_2  column_3
0        a        x         2
1        b        y         1
2        c        z         1
```

Another solution with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['column_3'] += np.where((df['column_1']=='a') & (df['column_2']=='x'), 1, 0)

print (df)
  column_1 column_2  column_3
0        a        x         2
1        b        y         1
2        c        z         1
```

Comment: Great.!! Would like to know if there are other methods as well to achieve this ? Or this being the only way to address my particular problem ?

Comment: @AmitPathak - Added another idea.